# How WordPress select wp_comment table ?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to select comments from my table ORDER BY date and Relate by parent_comments as WordPress comments.

This is my Table:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| comment_by      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| post            | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comment         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comment_parents | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date            | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to display like this:
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOicN.jpg)

```css
.row{
display:flex;
}
ul li{
list-style:none;
padding-left:15px;
}
a{
text-decoration:underline;
color:blue;
}
ul{margin:0px;}
.cmt{font-size:20px;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="cmt"><a>Jonh</a> : I like this post.</div>
  <ul>Replay:
    <li><a>Admin</a> : Thanks</li>
    <li><a>Lina</a> : I like this post too.</li>
    <li><a>Admin</a> : Thanks.</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cmt"><a>Mr Jenny</a> : Wow great!</div>
  <ul>Replay:
    <li><a>Admin</a> : Thanks</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cmt"><a>Mr Toto</a> : Thanks for this post!</div>
</div>
```

I want to select comment : parent comment is ORDER BY date DESC and reply comment is order by date DESC too. 
I try to select :

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post = 1 GROUP BY comment_parents ORDER BY date DESC
```

But the result is comment_parents is not selected.

Comment: use `wp_list_comments()` to list all comments

Comment: From a pure MySQL point of view, this may be hard to do, because you need a recursive query to dive down the entire hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you so much!